# What is the most time efficient way to square each element of a vector of vectors c++

Tags: c++

I currently have a vector of vectors of a float type, which contain some data:

```
 vector<vector<float> > v1;
 vector<vector<float> > v2;
```

I wanted to know what is the fasted way to square each element in v1 and store it in v2? Currently I am just accessing each element of v1 multiplying it by itself and storing it in v2. As seen below:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        v2[i][j] = v1[i][j]*v[i][j];
     }
  }
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to delete the contents of `v1`?

Comment: Parallelism, e.g, use `std::async` for each (internal) vector.

Comment: yes it is acceptable to delete the contents of v1

Comment: OpenMP and OpenCL come to mind if you go the parallel route. Depends on the vector length and how many of these calculations you are doing.

Comment: In this example I used arbitrary numbers of a 10 by 10 vector array. But in my application the vector array at max will be a 2000 by 2000 vector array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of luck, the compiler you are using understands what you want to do and converts it so it uses sse-instruction of the cpu which do your squaring in parallel. In this case your code is close to the optimal speed (on single core). You could also try the eigen-library (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) which provides some more reliable means to achieve high performance. You would then get something like

```
ArrayXXf v1 = ArrayXXf::Random(10, 10);
ArrayXXf v2 = v1.square();
```

which also makes your intention more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in CPU world, OpenMP should help you easily. A single `#pragma omp parallel for` will divide the load between available cores and you could get further gains by telling the compiler to vectorize with `ivdep` and `simd` pragmas.

If GPU is an option, this is a matrix calculation which is perfect for OpenCL. Google for OpenCL matrix multiplication examples. Basically, you can have 2000 threads executing a single operation or fewer threads operating on vector chunks and kernel is very simple to write.

Comment: Thank you i'll definitely check out both OpenMP and OpenCL.

Comment: I am not sure about "perfect for OpenCL". There is very little computation going on and the loop is likely to be memory-bound.

Comment: The amount of computation depends on the size of the vectors I guess. If they are not big enough, OpenCL will be more overhead than good.